# ionic: problems build ios for ipad

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

i have an issue and doesnt know how to look for errors…
my actual situtation:

- android build works fine
- ios build for iphone works fine
- ios build for ipad works also but `<ion-content>` area is empty
- ios build for ipad with livereload works also fine

is there a way to look for errors why the ion-content is empty for ipad?
with safari debugger there are no errors in the html console, also no errors in the build terminal

i think it has to do with the cordova-firebasex plugin, but i am not sure

thanks in advance for any hints or tipps

system info:
ionic 5 with angular and all plugins up to date

Comment: Hello, same for me.
On iphone, app work fine but on ipad all plugins not works and cordova variable is undefined ...
My cordova-plugin-firebasex is in version 11.0.3-cli but i not sure that is the problem because if I remove this plugin the problem persist.

Thank's for help

Comment: it's fix for me, ipad was not detect on ios platform by ionic, so all my code crash after splashscreen loading ...